# Summing based on multiple conditions in matching rows Excel

Tags: excel, sum, addition

I'm needing to sum column H if:

Any value in D matches B of the same row, and if any value in D matches a specific cell in L.
For example,

IF D:D = B:B on the same row, AND F:F on the same row != Y, AND D:D = L2, then SUM = 2.0

IF D:D = B:B on the same row, AND F:F on the same row != Y, AND D:D = L3, then SUM = 1.2

[image]

There will be a couple hundred  rows that will follow this.  I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B:B=D:D)*(F:F<>"Y")*(D:D=L2)*(H:H))
```

To make formula faster I suggest you to use exact ranges:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B2:B100=D2:D100)*(F2:F100<>"Y")*(D2:D100=L2)*(H2:H100))
```

Comment: Think I got it, my header row was causing the issue.